# How to convert from date to Hex in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I need to convert the minimum possible date in sql, that is 1753-01-01 in hexadecimal format, I have tried to do it this way but it shows me the same sentence.

```
SELECT cast('1753-01-01' AS binary(8))
```

Comment: there is no such thing as *a* hexidecimal format.  people use that term to mean all kinds of things.  please provide an example of the result you want.

Comment: and what do you mean by "the minimum possible date", anyway?

Answer (score 0):

I think we can try to use [`HEX`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_hex) function instead of `CAST`

```
SELECT HEX(dt)
FROM t
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=24dc151752e5ea9d78e7c5f84d6df520)